# passing clicked link text to php and and with that link text retrieving all images and displaying them in another page

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

The scenario is to send the clicked link text to server where i have kept images of the text say (caps) in a file system(images/caps/thumbnails) and the paths are saved in mysql database with this table desc

```
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| imgid  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| imgurl | varchar(75) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| family | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

with that text php retrieve all the images(say 50 images) via mysql from the file system opens products.html in new tab and display it there with that 50 images.
plz go throgh the whole code which i have in my pages and then reply

below is my menu bar code in my index.html.

```
<ul class="dropdown">

        <li><a href="#">Man</a>
            <ul class="sub_menu">
            <li><a href="#">Caps</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">T-shirts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Jeans</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Woman</a>
            <ul class="sub_menu">
                <li><a href="#">Caps</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Coats</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tshirts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jeans</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        </ul>
```

with below code i m grabbing the text if a user clicks the caps link the txt is grabbed below the alert is working but the $.ajax......no

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.sub_menu a').click(function() {
        var txt = $(this).text();  
        //alert("you clicked"+txt);
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'thegamer.php',
        data: {'txt':txt}
        });
    });
 });
```

further in my thegamer.php it is not get passed to this code as i m echoing it but not getting echoed

```
   <?php
    include 'dbconnect.php';
    $q=$_GET["txt"];
      echo $q;
    include 'dbclose.php';
    ?>
```

further with the clicked link text the php pulls with this query pulls the relevant images

```
select * from images where family='$q'
```

REMEMBER I DONT WANT THE AJAX TO RETRIEVE THE IMAGES OF CAPS AND DISPLAY ON THE SAME INDEX.HTML BUT TO OPEN A NEW WINDOW TAB WITH PRODUCTS.HTML AND DISPLAY THE IMAGES THERE

from further on here then how to play with that txt and retrieve images from the file system with mysql paths and further displaying that 50 images in products.html inside a divs i am completely blank i tried all the stackoverflow relevant questions and google but cant get an idea and process it

anyone please help me to go on further with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this:

```
var txt = $(this).text();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'thegamer.php',
    data: 'txt=' + txt,
    });
```

OR with your code:

```
var txt = $(this).text();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'thegamer.php',
    data: {send_txt: txt},
    success: function( data ){
      //now echo the data where you want
      // for example
      $('#result').html( data );
      // or you can see in on firebug
      console.log( 'Return:' + data );
    }
    });
```

note that `send_txt` is a post variable which you can get with like `$_REQUEST['send_txt']`, hope it will work

Comment: the main problem is if it gets send then how to open the thegamer.php and echo it there

Comment: @sajid now see i edited the second section on the above codes, and suggest you to use firebug extension(firefox) to check and debug the ajax request etc. `$('#result')` is i give an example where you can print the data, you can replace the id with your requirment..

Comment: '<?php
include 'dbconnect.php';
$q=$_REQUEST['send_txt'];

  echo $q;
include 'dbclose.php';
?>' this is giving error                       Notice: Undefined index: send_txt in C:\wamp\www\new\thegamer.php on line 12

Comment: done great man when pressing the link the value is passed as i m seeing it in console but $('#result').html( data ); this is problem i want to open the data in products.html in div how to target that

Comment: @sajid form which page you will send the request form jquery??

Comment: console.log( 'Return:' + data );
 is giving this on console Resource id #5